# Why does “WD Anywhere Backup” keep crashing on my vista machine?

Tags: windows-vista, backup

On my vista machine, most weeks I am told the “WD Anywhere Backup” has stop working and needs to be restarted.

Any anyone come across this problem?

What should I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try installing the latest version of the software

http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=111&sid=87&lang=en

You need to register your WD product before you can download the software, see link at bottom of the webpage

.

Or contact WD via email about your issue

http://support.wdc.com/contact/index.asp?wdc_lang=en

.

Comment: thanks I had already tied updating it, but I am acepting this answer as it may help someone else.